# Value of C-u universal-argument without digits

Tags: emacs

Is the value of `universal-argument` multiplier guaranteed to be 4 in future versions of emacs?

The [entry in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html#index-universal_002dargument-165) doesn't describe it directly, but using `C-h f` says that

> C-u without digits or minus sign provides 4 as argument.
>
> Repeating C-u without digits or minus sign multiplies the argument by 4 each time.

(emacs version 24.3.1)

---

For what it's worth, I'm using `call-interactively` and want to set `current-prefix-arg` properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the maintainers might want to chip in, but I can't imagine this ever changing.

Aside from the fact that it's probably the *best*<sup>1</sup> value for it, there is simply too much code out there which relies on the raw value `(4)`, or the numeric value `4`.

Now that's not a *guarantee*, but your code would be far from the only thing which broke if they were to change this, so I'm sure that such a change would be telegraphed *long* in advance to give people as much time as possible to adapt.

(The value *is* hard-coded, btw. There isn't a variable you can use instead.)

<sup>1</sup> Considering that odd numbers are likely less desirable, and the even numbers either side are 2 (which is barely useful on its own, and when squared is only doubled to 4), and 6 (which is squared to 36 which is far too large an increase).

Besides, I think if there was any feeling that there was an advantage to be gained from changing this value, the discussion and change would have happened long before now.

---

**Edit:**

It's probably worth noting here that if you want to test for the use of <kbd>C-u</kbd> *without* a number, you can simply test `(consp arg)`, provided that you've used `(interactive "P")` to gain the raw value, as the raw value is a list when no specific number is entered by the user.

If you care about how many times <kbd>C-u</kbd> was used, you'll also need to check `(prefix-numeric-value arg)`.

If you're not sure how it works, call this command with the various different ways of specifying a prefix argument, and you'll get the idea quickly enough:

```el
(defun foo (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (message "%s" arg))
```

See also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Prefix Command Arguments` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: +1 that.  It would take more than "an act of Congress," if you know what I mean.