# Default universal argument emacs (C-u)

Tags: emacs

If I press C-u C-n the cursor goes down of 4 lines.
Can I make the default universal argument to be another number greater than 4?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? (Note that if your preferred default number is a single digit (e.g. `9`) then it is just as easy to use `M-9` as it is to use `C-u`.)

Comment: @Drew, I didn't consider that. This is a better solution than mine, in my opinion.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/16755414

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better way to do this, but one possibility is to create your own universal argument prefix function. Here is the original function (as you can see `4` is hardcoded in the function):

```
(defun universal-argument ()
  "Begin a numeric argument for the following command.
Digits or minus sign following \\[universal-argument] make up the numeric argument.
\\[universal-argument] following the digits or minus sign ends the argument.
\\[universal-argument] without digits or minus sign provides 4 as argument.
Repeating \\[universal-argument] without digits or minus sign
 multiplies the argument by 4 each time.
For some commands, just \\[universal-argument] by itself serves as a flag
which is different in effect from any particular numeric argument.
These commands include \\[set-mark-command] and \\[start-kbd-macro]."
  (interactive)
  (setq prefix-arg (list 4))
  (universal-argument--mode))
```

In your init file, you can create your own custom version of this, and bind it to `C-u`:

```
(defun my-universal-argument ()
  (interactive)
  (setq prefix-arg (list 10))
  (universal-argument--mode))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-u") 'my-universal-argument)
```

However, see **@Drew**'s comment below about why this might not be a great idea, and may have undesired/unexpected consequences.

Also, keep in mind that you can press `C-u` multiple times as a prefix argument to multiply the repetitions by 4. For example, using the original default of `4`, `C-u C-u C-n` will move down 16 (4*4) lines, and so on.

Comment: I thought `C-u C-u C-n` moved down 16 lines.

Comment: @torazaburo yes, you are correct. I misread the documentation and didn't test that part thoroughly. Thanks for pointing that out! I will update my answer!

Comment: However, if you do that (replace 4 by 10) then some existing Emacs behavior will be broken (anything that depends on a raw prefix arg resulting in `(4)`, `(16)`, `(64)`,... I suggest you ask yourself seriously **why** you think you want to do this.

Comment: @Drew thanks for pointing this out. I didn't realize that would happen.

Comment: Yes, that's the show-stopper here. Those known raw values based on powers of 4 are *the* way to determine how many times `C-u` was typed, so this idea is really a non-starter.

Comment: Can you please me make some examples of what will be broken?

Comment: @LucaMarconato make sure to tag the person your question is directed to. I don't personally know of anything that will be broken, and the users that do know will not see your question unless you tag them ;)

Comment: @phils I tag you for the commend that I have written before

Comment: In the 25.1 codebase, some examples are `c-indent-command`, `delete-duplicate-lines`, `desktop-save`, `[lrzr]grep`, `vc-git-grep`, and *dozens* of `idlwave-*`, `reftex-*`, and `org-*` commands.